# Can the new UWB iPhones measure their distance towards other UWB iPhones?

Tags: ios, uwb

Is it practically possible for a developer right now (or at least theoretically in the future) to develop an App that can measure via UWB, the distance towards other Iphones?

UWB technology can take different forms in terms of ranging techniques. How does (or will) ranging work in these iPhones?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the iPhone11 schematic, found uwb chip U1 support 5 antennas, three of which are used for AOA positioning, the other two support uwb channel 5 and channel 9 data transmission, Now the iPhone and AirTag positioning, should be carried out through 3 AOA antennas, the other 2 should be used to support the iPhone as a tag (position with other iPhone phones, or anchor/node) use.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It might be an late answer, iOS provides Nearby Interaction framework to get distance and direction information.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/nearbyinteraction